# Analyze a model and create outer shell/layer of it programmatically

Tags: 3d, three.js

So we created a viewer for viewing CAD-models using  WebGL and Three.js. 
Right now we are trying to support loading only the outer shell of a building to decrease the cost of memory and rendering speed of viewing multiple large buildings. What we basically want to do is to take a model with one large building and remove everything inside the building so that the only thing you see is the outer walls, windows and doors.

Do anyone have an idea of how i could go about analyzing this and creating the shell of a model? Each wall, door, window etc. are loaded as individual objects right now and i have of course access to the vertices and faces.

Comment: This is not to answer your question. Just out of curiosity, how large is your models? I mean how many triangles? We have loaded models with 45 million triangles using threejs and thats without using instances and got 60+ fps. I think you can load more than that without thinking about fps.

Comment: We have models with 100k - 300k faces and see some fps drop on those. We are going to support loading 10-20 of these models at the same time or at least so you can see the outline of the model. What technique did you use to load that many triangles? keep in mind that each object in our model must be separate and selectable so merging geometry with the same material would not work with our selection.

Comment: We had to merge all the geometries into a single geometry to get 90 fps for 45M triangle model. We managed the selection and other features using body-vertex index map. Even that, i dont think 10-20 drawcalls of 100K-300K triangles will reduce the fps under 60. 10-20 drawcalls should be fine. I think, one single building got multiple parts(drawcalls). I think you can try to reduce that to a single drawcall.

Comment: yea if i could get merging geometry to work with selection that would be a great improvement! Right now i have like 10k drawcalls for 200k faces so getting that down to 10-100 calls would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively easy way is to take an idea from picking. You render the house from 4 to 6 sides (left, right, front, back, top, bottom). In each render you render each piece of the house in a different solid color (no lighting). You then call `gl.readPixels` or the THREE.js equivilent and scan all the pixels to find out which objects are still visible. Whichever ones are not visible are inside.

The complications are windows. If you have any kind of semi-transparent objects you need to NOT draw those otherwise they'll block the stuff inside that you are supposed to be able to see through them.

Another complication is semi-obscured wholes. Like if you have a vent and from a certain angle you can see through the vent to stuff inside but that angle is not visible from your 6 views then the stuff inside won't show up as visible.

In pseudo code

```
 for (ndx = 0 to numObjects) {
     someMaterial.color = ndx;
 }
 visibleObjects = [];
 for each camera position {
     render scene
     read pixels
     for each pixel {
         visibleObjects[pixelValue] = true
     }
 }
 notVisibleObjects = [];
 for (ndx = 0 to numObjects) {
     if (!visibleObjects[ndx]) {
         notVisibleObjects[ndx] = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yea that's a great idea but the issue is also buildings that block the view from an angle. Like a building with two "towers" so each building is blocking one surface of the other building. The issue with windows is not a big deal i think. We can make them solid instead of transparent because we are only using this view for viewing models at a distance. When you get closer to the actual building we then load more detail for that building on the fly.